# how to backup consul cluster data over to S3 storage

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, consul

Could someone please advice how to take the backup of Consul cluster datastore to S3. I know we can use EBS snapshot but I would like to have a script to move the Consult datastore over to S3 instead of snapshot approach which is not very effective.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Consul-Snapshot](https://github.com/pshima/consul-snapshot) at work to backup our Consul data centers. You can provide AWS credentials or use an IAM role so Consul-Snapshot can upload the snapshots to an AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: AWS S3 available only in Enterprise subscription, to have s3 store, you need some scripting